# How can I make LibreOffice's buttons visible again?

Tags: 16.04, icons, themes, libreoffice

Buttons on my toolbar in LibreOffice are essentially invisible. It's very hard to distinguish them from one another and to tell what each one is for. It has not always been that way and I do not know what's wrong with this. How can I fix it?

[image: LibreOffice screenshot]

Comment: What theme is that?

Comment: Looks like Arc Dark theme to me. See https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme/issues/684.

Comment: I've seen a few glitches with icon themes or text. Usually they're fixed by logging out and in (which restarts X), or restarting the PC.